# Report and Graphic in access 2007 - calculating values on queries

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2007

Picture a table with fields (Id, Valid, Value)

Valid = boolean
Value = number from 0 to 100

What I want is a report that counts the number of records where (valid = 0), and then gives me the total number of cases where (value < 70) and the number of cases where (value >= 70).

The problem is that the "value" field could be empty on some of the records and I only want the records where the value field is not empty.

I know that the second value (value>=70) is going to be calculated, but the problem is that I can't simply do (total number of records - number of records where value < 70), because there's the problem with the records where "value" is null...

And then I want to create graphic with these values, to see the percentage of records below and above 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*The problem is that the "value" field could be empty on some of the records and I only want the records where the value field is not empty.*"

Use a `WHERE` clause to exclude rows whose "value" field is Null.

Here is sample data for `tblMetraton`.

```
Id Valid Valu
 1    -1    2
 2     0    4
 3    -1    6
 4     0
 5     0   90
```

I used `Valu` for the field name because `Value` is a reserved word.

You can use the `Count()` function in a query and take advantage of the fact it only counts non-Null values.  So use `Count()` with an `IIf()` expression which returns a non-Null value (I used 1) for the condition you want to match and Null otherwise.

```
SELECT
    Count(IIf(Valid=0,1,Null)) AS valid_false,
    Count(IIf(Valu<70,1,Null)) AS below_70,
    Count(IIf([Valu]>=70,1,Null)) AS at_least70
FROM tblMetraton AS m
WHERE (((m.[Valu]) Is Not Null));
```

Based on my sample data in `tblMetraton`, that query gives me this result set.

```
valid_false below_70 at_least70
          2        3          1
```

If my sample data does not address the variability you're dealing with, and/or if my query results don't match your requirements, please show us you own sample data and the results you want based on that sample.

Comment: that solved my problem regarding the report. But I also want to show that results on a chart. I only want to show the below_70 and at_least70, saying that from 4 cases, 3 are below and 1 at_least. And show the percentages... But access only shows me the below or the at_least option, not both...how I can do a graph based on two calculated fields? sorry for the dumb question but I'm really stuck in here...

Comment: I could help with the data question, but not the chart question.  However I realize you need both questions answered.  I can delete my answer so that you may attract more interest to the chart part of your question.  And I'll gladly do that if you want.

Comment: No problem, let's wait a few more days to see if anyone helps on the chart question! :)